# How to run Angular 5 client inside Springboot Application on the same port as of the Springboot services within the same application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a Angular 5 + Springboot application, the angular frontend is running on a separate port and Springboot services on another. Is there some way I can run both on the same port and differentiate them with a baseUrl ?

for example

```
localhost:8090/api/..... for services
localhost:8090/client/index.html .... for frontend
```

Comment: config path as static resources - as Angular is static application. You can also put everything as web resources and it will work out of the box ;)

Comment: @Antoniossss In my angular-cli.json I have the static path entered as below: "outDir": "../src/main/resources/static"....... Is this what you mean? And also I dont understand what you mean by putting everythign as a web resource. can you please explain ?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot